# Populating a TextBox from a text file

Tags: c#

Im trying to get specific lines from a file and put them in a another string or maybe if we can put it in anothe textbox it wont be a prob :P

```
string[] msglines;

msglines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\xA\Desktop\MESSAGES.txt");

for (int x = 0; x < msglines.Length; x++)
{
    this.textBox5.Text = msglines[c];
    c = c + 2;
}
```

I get a :
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: What is this "c" in the loop and why don't you use "x"? Why do you add 2 to the "c"?

Comment: Probably a typo but you don't need the double \\ in the filepath

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get every second line.

Change your loop to

```
//Odd Lines
for (int x = 0; x < msglines.Length; x = x + 2)
{
    this.textBox5.Text += msglines[x];
}

//Even Lines
for (int x = 1; x < msglines.Length; x = x + 2)
{
    this.textBox5.Text += msglines[x];
}
```

As was pointed out in the comments, you can shorten `x = x + 2` to `x += 2`

And in the interest of LinqY Goodness...

```
//ODDS
msgLines
    .Where((str, index) => index % 2 == 0)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(str => textBox1.Text += String.Format("{0}\r\n", str));

//EVENS
msgLines
    .Where((str, index) => index % 2 == 1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(str => textBox1.Text += String.Format("{0}\r\n", str));
```

Comment: why is the second, fourth, sixth etc the odd lines?  This is 0 based indexing, so 0, 2, 4 are all odd!

Comment: I think to put EVERY odd line into textbox (as is required) you need to write:  this.textBox5.Text +=msglines[x];

Answer (score 3):

your loop is controlled by x, but you're indexing by c [hence you need logic to prevent c getting greater than size of the array]

Answer (score 3):

Because you are increasing the line index (`c`) by 2 each time; just use `x`:

```
this.textBox5.Text = msglines[x];
```

Of course, from a loop this will result in just the last line being shown. What line is it you *actually* want to show?

---

Edit re comment; in which case, simply:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 1; x < msglines.Length; x+=2)
{
    sb.AppendLine(msglines[x]);
}
this.textBox5.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I want every odd line to sent to textbox...thats why I used c in there which is int'd from c=1

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, you are using c. You need to use x. Could I suggest that you have a look at the [reference for for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

Try this instead...

```
string[] msglines;

msglines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\xA\Desktop\MESSAGES.txt");


for (int x = 0; x < msglines.Length; x++)
{
    this.textBox5.Text = msglines[x];                       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use X as an index, with a step of 2, instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I'll use an example of taking every other character from a string, but the case of taking every other line from an array of strings is analogous.

Lets take "Hello" as an example for your msglines string

[image]
<sub>(source: [javabat.com](http://www.javabat.com/doc/string_index.png))</sub>

and let us say that your global variable c i initialized to 0 before you enter the for loop. Your msglines.Lenght will be 5. In the the fourth iteration through the loop (x == 3) you are going to try to access msglines[6], which is outside of the bounds of the array, hence the error.

You probably wanted something along the lines of

```
int x = 0;
while(x <= msglines.Lenght){
  this.textBox5.Text += msglines[x];
  x = x + 2;
}
```

or

```
for(x=0; x <= msglines.Lenght ; x+=2){
  this.textBox5.Text += msglines[x];
}
```

To get the odd lines you would start with x initialized to 1.

As for which of the two fully equivalent versions above to use, I would suggest using the one that is more readable to you. In my experience that is always the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string[] msglines;

 msglines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\xA\Desktop\MESSAGES.txt");

 for (int x = 0; x < msglines.Length; x++)
  {

      this.textBox5.Text = msglines[x++];

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want *all* odd-numbered lines in the TextBox, but your loop will only show the last line, as you overwrite the contents on each pass.

To show all odd-numbered lines, separated by line breaks:

```
string lineSep = "";
for (int x = 0; x < msglines.Length; x += 2)
{
    this.textBox5.Text += lineSep + msglines[x];
    lineSep = "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a double backslash in the `ReadAllLines()` call, causing it to fail opening the file.

Also, you are using `c` as an array index, it looks like you want `x`

Comment: Extra slashes are ignored (and forward slashes honoured as long as you use them semi consistenly) by the OS.  And it wouldnt throw an IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Ok. That still doesn't solve the fact that he is indexing his array wrong.

Comment: @Ruben - this isn't true, try it. It is puzzling though - if the msglines array was empty because of a failed read (though I'd expect an exception) then the for shouldn't be entered to produce the outofbounds exception. 'Course all of this is easily debuggable for the OP :S

Comment: @charlie: my point is that the error is in the loop, based on the exception. So you're just echoing my point by saying that still doesnt solve his problem (which my answer did).  I'm amused by how this question has mushroomed though!

Comment: @annakata: Paste "var l = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\Config.xml");
l.Dump();" into linqpad (dimecasts.net has great tutorials on same). It works. (Yes, dir c:\\users doesnt work in cmd.exe but does in PS. dir c:\users\\a\\b works in both). IOW it may seem because the parsing in cmd.exe is broken that double backslashes in paths are not allowed, but they are once you hand them to the windows APIs (thout it is possible that System.IO.File/Path do additional processing)

Answer (score 0):

The code i wrote is exactly how I want it to be.....

I actually want every odd line from my file to be sent to the textbox.and yeah P.S C initializes from 1

Comment: the code may be how you want it to be, but there are better ways of doing the same thing - clearly from the responses here your code is confusing which is as serious a problem as any

Comment: Imagine a msglines.Length of 5. Take a piece of paper and write down the values of c and x for each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already mentioned indexing problems of `c` versus `x`, you are also overwriting `textBox5.Text` on every iteration, so you'll only ever see the last line. It seems somehow unlikely to be intended behaviour. You might want something like this instead:

```
this.textBox5.Text += msglines[x]; // note x instead of c
```

Or if you really want everything and the +2 was a typo in itself you could do this without any loop:

```
this.textBox5.Text = String.Join( "\n", msglines );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return an IEnumerable that gives the odd numbered lines in a file:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetOddLines(string fileName)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    IEnumerator allLines = lines.GetEnumerator();
    while (allLines.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return (string)allLines.Current;
        if (!allLines.MoveNext())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the even numbered lines, just add a call to allLines.MoveNext() before the while loop.

Comment: Aside; you should always try to dispose enumerators; this is easier if you use the generic IEnumerator<T>, since that implements IDisposable. But if you want a streaming odd line reader, it would seem more efficient to start with StreamReader...

Comment: You are right of course... :-) The File.ReadAll*** methods tend to be quite slow but that is the price you pay for quick-and-easy I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the array with Length -1.   Array of 45 Length will only index to 44.